# redirect http to https without www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, redirect

I have the bottom code, and I want to get the domain always with https and never with www, the problem is when the URL is http://example.com not redirected to https://example.com

any ideas? thank you very much

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on      
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous single redirection rule was not working, try this combination of two checks:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu rapida respuesta, ahora si que me actualiza la url como quiero, pero el navegador despues de haber borrador la cache me indica: page does not work
the page being redirected too many times

Comment: @jesus Try changing `!=on [NC]` with `off [NC]`. Also, do you clear your browser cache, as you are using 301 redirection here.

Comment: update as you say !=on [NC] With off [NC] and clears the cache but does not work me, it tells me: page does not work the page being redirected too many times

Comment: @jesus Updated my answer above.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention, but with a simple .htaccess, practically your code alone does not work me. The problem is the condition of https, since the comment it works well only on condition www. It is very simple but it does not work because the code looks like this well. The error remains: page does not work the page being redirected too many times

Answer (score 0):

The recommended, best practice way to accomplish this is not with mod_rewrite at all, but rather putting Redirect directives in the various virtual hosts. This has the advantage of issuing a single Location header, and then never having to do these comparisons again. With a rewrite solution, you are comparing these values on every subsequent request to your website, greatly increasing the total overhead of serving content.

This is discussed in greater detail at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

An analogy would be asking someone at the front door whether they have come to the right house, rather than asking them every time they take a subsequent step, the rest of their visit.

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response, can be very good solution, but in my case work with a shared server, and can not have a virtual machine to access apache